# How to add form-data in jmeter

Tags: testing, jmeter, performance-testing

At POST API,
the developer has passed info with form-data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xJUZZ.png)

Need to test API in jmeter. But did not find an option for form-data.

So I tried to add with "parameter" and "Body Data", and now I am getting 400 at Response.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPNgg.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLQCq.png)

Answer (score 1):

`form-data` assumes submitting a [HTML Form](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp), all the [inputs](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_input.asp) need to be provided via "Name" and "Value" parameters:

[image]

If this is a [multipart/form-data request](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.html#section-3) -  you need to tick the appropriate box

[image]

In case you need to send any files - specify them in the Files Upload tab:

[image]

---

If your request works fine in Postman the easiest way of replicating it in JMeter would be just recording it using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)

1. Start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. [Import JMeter's certificate into Postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/), this way JMeter will be able to intercept and record [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/HTTPS) requests

   [image]
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/getting-started/proxy/) so the request to API would go through JMeter

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will generate HTTP Request Sampler and HTTP Header Manager
6. [Correlate](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/correlation-in-jmeter) dynamic parameters if needed and replace recorded hard coded values with the relevant [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)
7. If the request assumes any files upload - make sure that the file(s) are placed in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation.
8. You should be able to run the request successfully now